# How does PySNMP handle tables with read-create permissions?

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I'm new to SNMP, and finding it difficult to understand some of the mechanisms in PySNMP. I need to implement a table with read-create permissions to monitor and control a bridge on my network. I think it would be helpful if I had more clarity on one of the pieces of example code to understand what's happening in the framework when a manager attempts to create a new row.

I've been examining the sample code for [implementing a conceptual table](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html#implementing-conceptual-table) and executing the example snmpset/walk commands:

```
    $ snmpset -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.6.1.5.2.97.98.99 s “my value”
    $ snmpset -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.6.1.5.4.97.98.99 i 4
    $ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6
```

As far as I can tell, the set commands work because the MIB promises that `exampleTableColumn2` describes `OctetString` scalars. How is this data created/stored by the agent? Is a generic scalar object created with the suffix ".97.98.99," or is this information somehow associated with the instance of `exampleTableColumn2`? If I were to subsequently run an snmpget or snmpset command on the object we just created, what would I be interacting with in the eyes of the framework?

In a real-world implementation, the agent would really be querying the device to create a new entry in some internal table, and you would need custom scalar objects with modified readGet/writeCommit methods, but the sample code hasn't established scalar classes to implement get/set methods. By understanding how columns with read-create permissions should be handled in PySNMP, I think I can implement a more robust agent application. Any help/clarity is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is this data created/stored by the agent? Is a generic scalar object created with the suffix ".97.98.99," or is this information somehow associated with the instance of exampleTableColumn2?

This is a generic scalar value of type `OctetString` associated with a leaf node in a [tree of objects](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.py#L380) (MIB tree) of type `MibTableColumn`. In the MIB tree you will find a handful of node types each exhibiting distinct behavior (see docstrings), but otherwise they are very similar. Each node is identified by an OID.

> If I were to subsequently run an snmpget or snmpset command on the object we just created, what would I be interacting with in the eyes of the framework?

The MIB tree object responsible for the OID you are querying will receive [read*](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.py#L504) (for SNMP GET) or [read*Next](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.py#L713) (for SNMP GETNEXT/GETBULK) events to which it should respond with a value.

> In a real-world implementation, the agent would really be querying the device to create a new entry in some internal table, and you would need custom scalar objects with modified readGet/writeCommit methods

There are a couple of approaches to this problem, the way I've been pursuing it so far is to override some of these `read*`/`read*Next`/`write*` methods to read or write the value from/to its ultimate source (your internal table).

To simplify and keep your code in-sync with the MIB you are implementing, the pysmi library can turn a MIB into Python code with stubs via Jinja2 [templates](https://github.com/etingof/pysmi/blob/master/pysmi/codegen/templates/pysnmp/mib-instrumentation/managed-objects-instances.j2). From these stubs you can access your internal table whenever SNMP request triggers a read or write event. You can put your custom code into these stubs and/or into Jinja2 templates from which these stubs are generated.

Alternatively to implementing your own SNMP agent, you might consider this [general purpose](http://snmplabs.com/snmpresponder/) tool, which is driven by the [same technology](http://snmplabs.com/snmpresponder/mib-implementation/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the Jinja2 reference templates were especially helpful in understanding how MibTableColumn instances could be implemented. I'm assuming that the user implementation sections for read*/write* are where users would resolve which leaf object represented by the column is being referenced? To further my understanding of how the instances should be utilized, could you also explain what the use cases might be for customizing the create* methods?